# How to hide the table of content's heading?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

Is there any chance to hide the "Table of contents" heading that `\tableofcontents` generates?

If figured that `\renewcommand\contentsname{}` works (it sets the title to "", an empty string), but it does not remove the heading completely - the space is still blocked.

Comment: Isn't `\tableofcontents*` a better way to do it?

Comment: Doesn't work for me? I'm just getting that asterisk placed right below the heading.

Comment: `\tableofcontents*` removes the ToC entry from the ToC itself in the `memoir` class.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you are using the `article` class you can find the definition of `\tableofcontents` in the `article.cls` file:

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
```

Now you can just remove the part where `\section*` is defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{test}
\section{test2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How and why does this work? (Feel free to edit the answer into your answer)

Comment: @doncherry Just take the original definition of `\tableofcontents` from `article.cls` and remove the code that creates the heading.

Comment: I applied current validated answer ([see above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55088/148751/ "Validated answer")) and it didn't work at first. I had a *LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item* error message. All I had to do was to **add spaces** before `\tableofcontents`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want no TOC, but still want the "sidebar" created by hyperref you may do this:

```
\documentclass{...}
...
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\hidden}\sbox{\hidden}{\vbox{\tablefocontents}}

<code>
\end{document}
```

Comment: The bookmarks are produced independently of the presence of the TOC.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for this information, didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

You say that using an empty name does not remove the space before the TOC. You can change that using the extra code below:

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{} % the empty name

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\vspace{-5cm} % the removed space. Set as appropriate
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

Comment: A simple one-liner does it better (your solution didn't work for me) : `\renewcommand\contentsname{\vspace*{-20pt}}`.