# Remove the title of the toc in the book class

Tags: table-of-contents

As 
[How to hide the table of content's heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55080/how-to-hide-the-table-of-contents-heading)
I am trying to remove the table of contents title in the book class.
For this, like @Thorsten:

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
   \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

I delete the `\chapter*{}` part and `renewcommand` instead of `newcommand`

But it doesn't work, the title is still displayed.

**Any ideas for removing the title from the book class?**

Comment: did you replace `\chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%` with some thing like `\newpage`? can you please add MWE? let us know if you're using package like `etoc` or `titletoc` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of mind reading.

```
% tocnameprob.tex  SE 528429 remove toc title

\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{tocloft} % don't need this to eliminate ToC title

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{} % blank ToC title

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\end{document}
```

Read the `tocloft` documentation **2.2 Changing the titles** which talks about the general `\contentsname` and other `\...name` commands.

GOM

Comment: sorry for forgetting the MWE.
By following the recommended documentation it works: 

```\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} ``` (I forgot the option ```titles```).
**I will try to look better next time before posting.
Thank you so much.**

Answer (score 3):

The below tags works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
   \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I checked with your code. The problem comes from the ```tocloft``` package. Indeed, I seek to make appear the titles of section in ```sf``` in the ```toc```. When I remove this package the title of the ```toc``` is effectively deleted, but I no longer have my section titles in ```sf``` !

Comment: @Arnaud Until your comment there has been no mention of `tocloft`. It would really help if you provided an MWE (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) that exhibited your problem. We can sometimes be mind readers but usually never try. Did you try `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}` ?