# How to prevent "contents" to appear in header, while keeping it in `tableofcontents`?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

In a `classicthesis`, how to prevent "contents" to appear in header, while keeping it in `tableofcontents` ?

I tried [How to hide the table of content's heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55080/how-to-hide-the-table-of-contents-heading) but it did not work.

Comment: Did you try using `\pagestyle{plain}` just before `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: @Bernard It did the trick indeed ! Thanks. Why ?

Comment: Because the plain page style has no header, only a footer with the page number. Don't forget to revert to  your main page style after the table of contents.

Comment: @Bernard Indeed. How to revert the style after ?

Comment: Writing, after \tableofcontents, simply `\pagestyle{…}` (you have to know the name of the style). Or maybe simply write `{\pagestyle{plain}\tableofcontents}` (with the outer  pair of braces).

Comment: I'm using `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`. Thanks.